# How to delete a large file on LINUX server? (Load higher than 1.0 forces system into Read-only)

Tags: server, server-administration

I have created a java application which runs on a LINUX server and prints information to a log file.

The application was running fine, however the log file grew quicker than I expected and over a few days it took up all the available space on the server.

The java application is now stopped and I want to remove the excessive log file (11,264 MiB) to free up memory in order to start the process again.

When I log into the server I get the following message:

```
System information disabled due to load higher than 1.0
```

When I navigate via the command line to the file and try to remove it, I get the following:

```
$rm nohup.out
rm: cannot remove 'nohup.out': Read-only file system
```

I believe since the load is higher than 1.0 the system is forced into 'Read-only' mode. Does anybody have an idea how I could delete the file?

Does anybody have any suggestions?
I read something about perhaps using **fsck**, is this a viable option? 
If so, how would I use **fsck**?

Comment: No, your conclusion is not correct. A load average above 1.0 does not force any sane filesystem into read-only mode.

Comment: From [this link](http://superuser.com/questions/23498/what-does-load-average-mean-in-unix-linux) it explains that "Load average is a gauge of how many processes are on average, concurrently demanding CPU attention." Your right it seems the load average isn't the issue. After running `free -m` I also see that there is in fact some free space on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Can you remount the filesystem read-write?

https://askubuntu.com/questions/175739/how-do-i-remount-a-filesystem-as-read-write has the command line for that.

Comment: I could give it a try, however I am a little hesitant to do this command. From what I read it tries to set the filesytem into 'read/write' mode. However, I don't want to lose information in the file system, such as the MySQL database information. Is there any risk of this?

Comment: Yes, I mean essentially anything you do _could_ break something - I can't say how the system is set up or why it's in read only mode. However if you want to delete a file you will have to somehow make the filesystem writable eventually. You could back up first (or only back up the database perhaps) but please don't hold me responsible for data loss :-) all I'm saying is if you need to delete a file it won't work on a read only filesystem.